# Can I open a new window with other origin policy?

Tags: javascript

My problem is, that my page is on a https server, and when I'm opening a new blank window, I need to have it in http not https as its domain. Is it possibel, and if yes how?

```
window.open("","","")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you mean by "http not https as its domain"?  Popup windows are not AJAX calls, so I don't think the "same origin policy" applies.  Just open the `http://` page: `window.open("http://stackoverflow.com")`.

Comment: SOP doesn't apply to *open* the window, but it will apply if you want to talk to it later (i.e. pass data back and forth), same as it would for an iframe.

Comment: I'm trying to open a new blank window and pass an embed code into it, but the problem is, that the new window is opened in the same origin policy